# DataFrame object is not callable when counting length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I have a list of part numbers that I want to use to extract a list of prices on a website.

However I'm getting the below error when running the code:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/212677036/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 13, in 
>       data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN(i), "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
>   TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\Copy of MIC Parts Review - July 26 19.xlsx')
PN = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['Product code'])

#print(PN)
i = 0

Total_rows = PN.shape[0]
while i < Total_rows:

    data = {"partOptionFilter": {"PartNumber": PN(i), "AlternativeOemId": "17155"}}
    r = requests.post('https://www.partsfinder.com/Catalog/Service/GetPartOptions', json=data).json()
    print(r['Data']['PartOptions'][0]['YourPrice'])
    i=i+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `PN(i)`. That is why it says

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

The (i) is like a method call.

I am not sure how your df looks like and what you want to extract but you have to index the DataFrame like this:

```
PN[i]
```

or

```
PN.loc[i, 'columnname']
```

or

```
PN.iloc[i, 0]
```

or ... depending on your df

Comment: Thanks PN.ilock[i,0] worked.  However I'm getting empty outputs..My dataframe PN only consists of one column of part numbers.  When I run  print(PN.iloc[i,0]) I can see the outputs just fine..

Comment: Where do you get empty outputs?